Duplicate Entry Key error when initial 6 characters match
I have a table BLE_PINS with columns TN, MAC, PIN, and Date. MAC is the primary key. When entering
INSERT INTO `BLE_PINS` (`MAC`, `PIN`) VALUES ('SEEP413E68','99933');

I get the error

#1062 - Duplicate entry 'SEEP41' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

It seems to be matching only the first 6 characters. Is there a way to change that?
Table definition:
CREATE TABLE BLE_PINS ( 
    TN varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, 
    MAC varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    PIN varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    Date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (MAC(6)) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


What is the size of the MAC field in the table definitions?

@BartMcEndree VARCHAR with length 12.

Please add the output of show create table BLE_PINS

PRIMARY KEY (MAC(6))   <--this is your problem

@BartMcEndree I saw that, figured out how to change it. Thanks to you and Barmar

@Barmar Show create.. was a smart suggestion. If you add an answer I will upvote it.

PRIMARY KEY (MAC(6)) 

means that only the first 6 characters of MAC should be used as the primary key. This syntax is documented in Index Prefixes

With col_name(N) syntax in an index specification for a string column, you can create an index that uses only the first N characters of the column.

If you want the entire column to be the key, use
PRIMARY KEY (MAC) 


I am struggling to find documentation that explains why the MAC(6) syntax was allowed. I can understand ( MAC VarChar(6) ).  But I expect ( MAC (6) ) to return an error.

In an index definition, you can specify that just a prefix of the column should be indexed. This is mostly useful for string columns that are longer than the maximum length of an index. It's not usually useful for unique and primary keys, but it's not prohibited.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/column-indexes.html#column-indexes-prefix

Thanks. From the CREATE TABLE statement structure we get  [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY  [index_type] (key_part,...) [index_option] ...    I guess we could use a clear definition of what Key_Part can be.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/create-table.html

That's the same thing as "index specification" mentioned in the text I quoted.
